# How to add <tr></tr> after every fourth loop term of <td></td>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, for-loop

I want to break from the loop after every fourth term of number in the loop.

I want to create a list of twenty people; in every `tr` should to be 4 people.

So, I want to break from the loop after every 4<sup>th</sup> number of loop. My one `tr` will contain 4 `td`  and every `td` value is incremented with respect to the loop like the first `td` will 1 second will 2 and last will 4, then it should  break with a new `tr` and the value is in `td` like I said in increment order.

My code is below:

```
 <?php  for ($i = 0 ; $i<=20; $i++){?>
     <tr>

         <td>
             <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
             <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 1 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
             <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
         </td>
          <td>
             <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
             <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 2 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
             <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
         </td>

         <td>
             <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
             <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 3 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
             <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
         </td>

         <td>
             <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
             <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 4 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
             <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
         </td>

      </tr>

 <?php 
if($i%4==0){    echo "<tr></tr>";}


} ?>
```

Comment: your $i is starting from 0, so, $i%3  shuold work..

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju it really shouldn't, that will give every 3, the correct use is ($i+1)%4

Comment: the correct use will be to decide from 0 or 1 to 19 or 20

Comment: Well yes having 21 elements in his loop is wrong, but could arguably be a typo and is not related to his problem, but suggesting he should use modulo 3 instead of 4 when he wants it grouped by 4 is flat wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to stick my neck out and show an alternative aproach.
Normally you have an array of users.
This one will create a table with 4 cols, if you have 22 users only 20 will show in this example as it limits output to fill up each row.

```
$td = array();
$userlist = array( 'Bob', 'John', 'Robert', 'Eric', 'Lydia', 'Fanny', 'Alex', 'Leopold', 'Tom', 'Mark', 'Bob2', 'John2', 'Robert2', 'Eric2', 'Lydia2', 'Fanny2', 'Alex2', 'Leopold2', 'Tom2', 'Mark2' );

foreach( $userlist as $i => $user ) {

    if ( $i != 0 && $i%4 == 0 ) {
      $td[] = '<td> ' . implode( '</td><td>', $tdata ) . '</td>';
      $tdata = array();
    }

    $tdata[] = '<img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
                <a href="' . $i . '" class="user-link">Full name ' . $user . '</a>
                <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>'; 

}

echo '<table><tr>' . implode( '</tr><tr>', $td ) . '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add dummy variable $temp, then increment the value at each time if you get forth it will again starts with 1.

this is easiest way to do!!

```
    <?php  
    $temp =1;
    for ($i = 1 ; $i<=23; $i++){ if($temp == 1){   echo "<tr>"; } ?>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 1 ?>" class="user-link">Full name <?php echo $i ; ?></a>
            <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
        </td>
    <?php 
    if($temp == 4){ echo "</tr>"; $temp = 0; }
        $temp++;
    }
  if($temp-1 != 0 ){ echo '</tr>'; }
    ?>
```

Comment: just try this answers with no explanation result in copy paste code with no further understanding for anyone

Comment: @ toni sorry, I post a basic php so i think no need explaination, okay now i will addmy explaination

Comment: what's basic to someone with experience can be very confusing for someone learning, so I'd at least highlight the change

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php  for ($i = 5 ; $i<=20; $i+=4){ ?>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
                        <a href="<?php echo $i - 4 ; // shoud to be 1 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
                        <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
                        <a href="<?php echo $i - 3; // shoud to be 2 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
                        <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
                        <a href="<?php echo $i - 2; // shoud to be 3 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
                        <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
                        <a href="<?php echo $i - 1; // shoud to be 4 ?>" class="user-link">Full name 1</a>
                        <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
                    </td>

                </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your loop start at 4?

Answer (score -1):

change `if($i%4==0){    echo "<tr></tr>";}` to `if(($i+1)%4==0){ echo "</tr><tr>";}`

Comment: ...correct i used your check in my answer..you can check

Answer (score -1):

```
assume $rows = 20;

<?php  for ($i = 0 ; $i<=$rows; $i++){?>
    <tr>
        <?php if ($i<$rows){ 

        ?>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 1 ?>" class="user-link"><?php echo $rows[$i]['nickname']?></a>
            <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
            <?php   $i = $i+1;

             if ($i<$rows){ ?>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 1 ?>" class="user-link"><?php echo $rows[$i]['nickname']?></a>
            <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
            <?php
            $i = $i+1;

             if ($i<$rows){ ?>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 1 ?>" class="user-link"><?php echo $rows[$i]['nickname']?></a>
            <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>
            <?php
            $i = $i+1;
             if ($i<$rows){ ?>
        <td>
            <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="<?php echo $i ; // shoud to be 1 ?>" class="user-link"><?php echo $rows[$i]['nickname']?></a>
            <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
        </td>
        <?php } ?>

     </tr>

<?php 
if(($i+1)%4==0){ echo "</tr><tr>";}

} ?>
```

Comment: this is a lazy answer, at least format the code properly and better still explain why the answer works so the OP learns something, SO should primarily be about teaching folk, not providing copy paste code

Comment: @ToniLeigh  can u review again my answer....its not a copy paste.....if u can give better answer then this...then you should to comment and downgrade here .....

Comment: it's copy paste because it's just a block of code with a solution in, somewhere, i.e. it is likely that someone will just copy and paste rather than pick through it to find a solution they'll struggle to notice

Comment: @ToniLeigh no its not a copy paste....its copy from my editor..not from some where else......

Comment: that's not what I mean, I mean the answer only provides the asker with something to copy and paste, it doesn't provide them with any understanding or point out the correction