# Php output foreach into table, specify column number

Tags: php, multiple-columns

I want to output a list containing several thousand items into a table with 5 columns. Everything works except how to `echo` in the last `</tr>`. I've attempted several variations on the below code but either ended with one column, or unlimited columns. If it's just two columns I can do it another way. but I need 5 to optimise space. So the question is, how can I output a list of file names into 5 columns using php

```
    <?php
$i=0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
if ($i==4) { echo '</tr>'; 
    $i=0;
}
elseif ($i=0) { echo '<tr>'; 
}
echo '<td>
        <div>'.$file.'</div>
    </td>';

$i++; 
}
?>
```

Please assist

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @raveenanigam A table with 5 columns of filenames

Comment: acc.. to ur code u'll get 1 checkbox and a tag in each 5 td's...what's your problem now

Comment: Everything is ok, except I don't get 5 columns, the final </tr> to start a new row doesn't work, I'm not even sure if the first <tr> works either, so I just get endless <td></td>

Comment: can share the array of $files

Comment: what difference does it make? Even if I just have a number in each <td></td> thats not the problem. The problem is outputting to 5 columns. Something must be wrong with my if and ifelse bits, but I can't work out what

Comment: Have a look at this, similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794996/how-to-add-tr-tr-after-every-fourth-loop-term-of-td-td/32795334#32795334

Comment: @Tom I have just looked, I can't see how the accepted answer would work for me, and the rest are downvoted, very basic php knowledge. The accepted answer even if I could get it working is unnacceptable for what I need, because it doesn't show any list items that are over the limit of 20

Comment: any reason for the downvote? I can't learn if I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: @Kilisi - it outputs as many rows as you put data into it, just modify $i%4 to $i%5 to make it 5 columns.

Comment: Thanks for the 'heads up'. I have edited the question in an attempt to make it more suitable, let me know if that's insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using this code:

```
echo '<table><tr>'; 
for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
    if ($i%5 == 0) { 
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>'; 
    }       
    echo '<td>
            <div class="select-all-col"><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$files[$i].'"/>
            <a href="download-ui.php?name='.$foldername."/".$files[$i].'" style="cursor: pointer;">'.$files[$i].'</a></div>
            <br />
        </td>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Also, by using for instead of foreach you ensure you dont get any errors for an empty array.

Comment: no errors in the log, but nothing is output

Comment: Edited, forgot the count($files).

Answer (score 1):

As i commented and referred to a similar thread, here you have an example to get what you want. This creates a table with correct col count and rows.

```
$td = array();
$cols = 5;

foreach( $files as $i => $file ) {

    if ( $i != 0 && $i%$cols == 0 ) {
      $td[] = '<td> ' . implode( '</td><td>', $tdata ) . '</td>';
      $tdata = array();
    }

    $tdata[] = '<div class="select-all-col">
                  <input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="' . $file . '"/>
                  <a href="download-ui.php?name=' . $folderName . '/' . $file . '" style="cursor: pointer;">' . $file . '</a>
                </div>
                <br />';

}

// fill up empty cols at the end IF cols vs data dont add up
if ( !empty( $tdata ) ) {
    $create = $cols - count( $tdata );
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $create; $i++ ) {
        $tdata[] = ' - ';
    }
    $td[] = '<td> ' . implode( '</td><td>', $tdata ) . '</td>';
}

echo '<table><tr>' . implode( '</tr><tr>', $td ) . '</tr></table>';
```

Or in your way, this also works but leaves incorrect number of colums in the end if data list dont match up with filling up 5 columns

```
$i = 0;
$tdata = false;

foreach ( $files as $file ) {

  if ( $i != 0 && $i%5 == 0 ) { 
    $tdata .= '</tr><tr>';
  }

  $tdata .= '<td>
               <div class="select-all-col"><input name="select[]" type="checkbox" class="select" value="'.$file.'"/>
                 <a href="download-ui.php?name='.$folderName."/".$file.'" style="cursor: pointer;">'.$file.'</a>
               </div>
               <br />
             </td>';

  $i++; 
}

echo '<table><tr>' . $tdata . '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: the second solution will definitely come in handy, I'm not worried about the last row being different